# How do I configure an ASP.net web application to invoke a WCF service host factory for named pipe calls?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, named-pipes

I am hosting a WCF service in an ASP.net application.  The service has two endpoints, an HTTP endpoint and a named pipe endpoint.  I'm trying to consume the service from within the same web application using the named pipe endpoint.

The problem is that the service host factory isn't invoked until something tries to access the HTTP endpoint, so if the web application tries to call the service using the named pipe endpoint the call fails.

How do I configure the web application (or IIS) to invoke the service host factory for named pipe calls?

**Update**: My original premise was wrong.  I took Petar's advice and installed AppFabric.  This allowed me to see that the named pipe endpoint did in fact exist and that the service host factory had been invoked during an earlier build.  I was able to test this by performing a clean build and setting a break point in the factory class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Windows Server AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677312.aspx) could be your solution as it offers ability to manage service instance differently then with IIS and WAS. [You can see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677212%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) the screen where you can configure your services to auto start.

Beside this feature there are some other useful aspects of AppFabric you can read from the links above.

Comment: This isn't quite what I was looking for, but I'm learning a lot about AppFabric.  Thanks for the tip!